# Excel documents 'blanking' after a short delay

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2010

One of my clients is having a problem with certain Excel documents. Some of the worksheets go 'blank' after a short delay, after Enable Editing is clicked. The content is there before, and other people can access the document just fine. But this particular user cannot. Not all the tabs in a workbook are affected; the ones that appear most likely to be affected are those formatted to print nicely.

The documents still have formatting on the cells, but all the data is gone.
I cannot see any obvious change in this client's computer. Perhaps a recent patch (the issue just started)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution! There was a corrupt Custom View (or that View was just incompatible with her computer/version/display somehow). By clicking the Custom View button and choosing a different one than the blank one listed at the top, the content in the cells returned.